# Probem with terminal on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

i`m guess i am pressing CTRL + Z while running the interactive shell and this appears:

`[1]+  Parado                  python mana`

Parado = Stopped

how i rerun the stopped thing

from brazil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have sent the job to the background.
Check background jobs with `jobs` command, and bring it back using the `fg`command.
More about this here:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/job-control-bash-feature-you-only-think-you-dont-need